# C# Progress Bar based on event and delegate not working

Tags: c#

I need help in troubleshooting my code.  I have 3 classes.  Class 1 is a WinForm with Progressbar on it.  Class 2 is where the event is fired.  Class 3 is the EventArg for the progress.   The program compiles with out any errors, but when I click the button, the progress bar does not move!.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {
        //Declaring a delegate
        public delegate void StatusUpdateHandler(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e);

        //Declaraing an event
        public event StatusUpdateHandler OnUpdateStatus;

        public int recno;

        public void Func()
        {
            //time consuming code
            for (recno = 0; recno <= 100; recno++)
            {
                UpdateStatus(recno);
            }
        }

        public void UpdateStatus(int recno)
        {    
            // Make sure someone is listening to event         
            if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return;          <--------------OnUpdateStatus   is     always null not sure why?
            ProgressEventArgs args = new ProgressEventArgs(recno);         
            OnUpdateStatus(this, args);     
        } 
    }
}

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Class1 testClass;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            testClass = new Class1();
            testClass.OnUpdateStatus += new Class1.StatusUpdateHandler(UpdateStatus);
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 c = new Class1();
            c.Func();
        }

        public void UpdateStatus(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
            progressBar1.Value = e.Recno;
        }
    }
}

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public  int Recno { get; private set; }

        public ProgressEventArgs(int recno)
        {
            Recno = recno;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't make a delegate type; instead, use `EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two different objects of Class1.

In button click handler, the object `c` is not the same as member object `testClass`. Use `testClass` in place of `c` and it shud work

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testClass.Func();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never added an event handler to `c`'s event.

You did add a handler to `testClass`' event, but `testClass` is never used.

Comment: can you please elaborate further.

Comment: `c` and `testClass` hold two different instances with two different events.  You only added your handler to one of them.